# Windows command find : looking for a string OR another

Tags: find

Using the `find` command, I'd like to look for a string or another.

It seems this is not possible, but I'd like to make sure I didn't overlook a way to do it.

Comment: Do you mean DOS or CMD?

Comment: I mean CMD ! I updated my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If, by chance, you are talking about Windows command line (**which is not DOS**), then there is `findstr`:

```
findstr "one two three"
```

Yes, quoted as single argument. Alternative syntax which allows spaces in strings:

```
findstr /c:"one" /c:"two"
```

*`findstr` claims to support regular expressions, but I could not get `one|two` to work.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with the dos `find` command.

However you can do this with grep - there's a windows/dos version of grep available with the [GNUWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) utilities at Sourceforge.